# What is an antiderivative and can 1 function have more than one antiderivatives?

Tags: integration

I want to know what the definition of an antiderivative is really. I know that the antiderivative of a function between 2 limits will give you the area under the graph between these limits. Take the function $y = 1/(-2x)$. The integral will be $-(1/2) \ln|x|$ or it can also be $-(1/2)\ln(2|x|)$ which is equal to $-0.5 \ln(2) -0.5 \ln|x|$. so as you can see they differ only by a constant. So when you plug in two limits you will get the same value. But i am wondering what an antiderivative represents exactly and how can it be possible as you saw to have a function with 2 antiderivatives. And by the way, can an antiderivative be represented by a graphical method?

Comment: If you read any good calc book these questions can be cleared up.

Comment: maybe i'll try watching a youtube video on that.

Comment: Yes good idea. I don't know much about such videos but I hear the Khan Academy has good ones on calc, algebra, etc.

Answer (score 2):

An antiderivative is just a function whose derivative is the function you're after. So in your example, $-0.5\ln|x|$ and $-0.5\ln|2x|$ are *both* antiderivatives of $\frac{-1}{2x}$. A function actually has *infinitely many* antiderivatives, because the $+C$ you get can be any real number. The reason there are so many is that taking a derivative eliminates any constant terms, so adding a constant to an antiderivative doesn't change the fact that taking its derivative gets you back the original function.

Comment: well yeah, sure

Answer (score 1):

If you understand a derivative, you will understand that the derivative of a constant is $0$.

You will also know that the derivative of $f(x) + g(x)$ equals the derivative of $f(x)$ plus the derivative of $g(x)$, for appropriate conditions on $f$ and $g$.

That means that if $c$ is a constant, the derivative of $f(x) + c$ is the same as the derivative of $f(x)$.

So, suppose $F(x)$ is the derivative of $f(x)$.

That is, $f(x)$ is the **antiderivative** of $F(x)$.

Then $F(x)$ is also the derivative of $f(x) + c$, whatever $c$ is.

And in this context, $c$ can be any real number.

That means there are as many different antiderivatives of $F(x)$ as there are real numbers -- an uncountable infinity of them.

It can also be shown (but it needs a bit more advanced thinking) that if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both antiderivatives of $F(x)$, then $g(x)$ is *always* going to be $f(x) + c$, where $c$ is a constant.

That is, of all the antiderivatives of a given function, they are all the same except for being different by a constant.

As for a graphical method, the antiderivative of $f$ is the function whose gradient is $f$. You can get an approximation to it by picking a point in the plane (any point), say at $x = x_0$, and calculate $f(x_0)$. Then you draw a short arrow with that gradient. The end of that arrow is at $x = x_1$. You calculate $f(x_1)$ and draw another short arrow with the gradient equal to $f(x_1)$, that is, the gradient at that point. And so on, drawing a line made up of short arrows. As the length of the arrow tends to $0$, the line represents the curve that is an antiderivative of $f$.

The above is called **Euler's method**.

Comment: maybe you're doing more advanced maths than me as i didn't know about that theory you mentioned: ''You will also know that the derivative of f(x)+g(x) equals the derivative of f(x) plus the derivative of g(x), for appropriate conditions on f and g.''. can you explain that please?

Comment: but you've contradicted yourself. : you said that g(x) was a function and that c was a constant. and then you said that g(x)=c. a constant is not a function ?

Comment: or maybe i'm wrong. is it?

Comment: @butterfly I don't know where you're learning maths from if you haven't been taught this most basic of stuff. The fact that differentiation is a linear operation is one of the first things that you need to be aware of. And yes, a constant can be a function. $\forall x \in \mathbb R: g(x) = c$ is a perfectly good function definition. My advice to you is: study your text book. If you have not been given a text book but are learning calculus randomly from a teacher who hasn't taught you this stuff, then get one. Any calculus text, it won't matter what.

Comment: oh, actually i knew how to differentiate two functions that are added up or substracted , i just didn't know about it as being a rule...